# Any examples of UDPServer and joining multicast group?

Tags: reactor-netty

Just getting started with Netty-Reactor and was wondering if anyone had any examples on how to use the UdpServer to join a multicast group and process the incoming packets. I'd also like to use UdpClient to send messages over the wire.

The current documentation is a little sparse on examples.

I'm confused how much of Netty custom objects I need to write versus what the Netty-Reactor project hides from me.. I see there are UdpInbound and UdpOutbound.. how are those related to channel encoder and decoders? Do I still need those?

I'd like to make an example of a UDP server listening on a multicast group and to listen for Google Protobuf messages send to the group. I know how to do all the protobuf processing off the wire..

I'm just not sure how to do the actual listening on the wire with Netty-Reactor.

I see there is UdpInbound.join() which looks like what I want..but I'm lost after that.

Can anyone point me to examples?

Thanks

UPDATE:

@Violeta - Thanks for the help and link! It helped me a litte bit more.

I think I found a bug? or maybe I misunderstand how to get both IPv4 and IPv6 working on the same server. I noticed in your example code that you use the  `.runOn(resources, InternetProtocolFamily.IPv4)`.

Without this code, my binding fails when I have an InetInterface that has both IPv4 and IPv6 address assigned.

I would like to support both IPv4/IPv6 on the same server and all interfaces since the code will run on multi-homed machines.

I don't see a way to specify the `InternetProtocolFamily` on the connection other than to use the `.runOn` method.

I get the following error:

```
IFace: name:en0 (en0) Address class: /fe80:0:0:0:1ce8:a828:3c15:4f4b%en0 is Inet4Address = false
IFace: name:en0 (en0) Address class: /192.168.1.151 is Inet4Address = true
09:42:35.615 [udp-nio-1] INFO server.Application - Joining iFace name:en0 (en0) to Multicast Group /224.0.0.224 
09:42:35.621 [udp-nio-1] ERROR reactor.Flux.ConcatArray.1 - onError(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IPv6 socket cannot join IPv4 multicast group)
09:42:35.623 [udp-nio-1] ERROR reactor.Flux.ConcatArray.1 - 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IPv6 socket cannot join IPv4 multicast group
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.innerJoin(DatagramChannelImpl.java:814)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.join(DatagramChannelImpl.java:900)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:414)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:391)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:384)
    at reactor.netty.udp.UdpOperations.join(UdpOperations.java:65)
    at server.Application.lambda$null$2(Application.java:45)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UdpInbound.join()` returns `Mono<Void>`, the publisher will be complete when the group has been joined.
After that you can start receiving packages using `UdpInbound.receive()`.

```
in.join(...)
  .thenMany(in.receive()
              ...)
...
```

See [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/ff2b71d07f87cda45a4df23bca35418c8bf5e45e/reactor-netty-core/src/test/java/reactor/netty/udp/UdpServerTests.java#L131) for some examples.

You can use either `handler` method for handling the I/O (as it is in the link), or you can just bind and when you receive the `Connection`, you can invoke `Connection.inbound()` and then you can join and start receiving packages.

About decoders/encoders we encourage you to use the operators from Reactor Core for transforming the incoming packages. If you cannot achieve this with that approach you can always add a standard Netty handler, using for example `doOnBound(conn -> conn.addHandler...)`

Comment: Thanks! I did run into a problem and updated my question with the details. Any ideas?

Comment: yes you have to specify `runOn`, if you do not specify `runOn` it will use what is the default for the OS

Comment: Do i have to create two connections then? One for IPv4 and another for IPV6 and have them both share the same EventLoop?

Or can I call `.runOn` multiple times? in the source code it creates a new `UdpServerRunOn` instance..so I wasn't sure